# instance declaration and convert string to Maybe type

Tags: haskell

An guessing and answering game. 
Each Card comprises a Suit, one of A,B,C,D,E,F,G, and a Rank, one of 1|2|3.

I need to have a function to guarantee input(String) whether is valid type. And also write an instance declaration so that the type is in the Show class.

I am not sure about the function toCard, how to express "String" in the function and meet it with the condition.

```
data Suit = A|B|C|D|E|F|G 
            deriving (Show , Eq)

data Rank = R1|R2|R3
              deriving (Show, Eq)

data Card = Card Suit Rank
             deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Show Card where show (Card a b) 
     = show a ++ show (tail show b)

toCard :: String -> Maybe Card
toCard all@(x:xs)
        | (x=A|B|C|D|E|F)&&(xs==1|2|3) = Just Card
        | otherwise  = Nothing
```

edit toCard function, input should be any String, so i use a list expression, but it seems to be not correct, cause i try it in ghci, (x=A|B|C|D|E|F)&&(y==1|2|3) is not valid

Comment: That code doesn't look correct. I think you need parenthesis around `Card a b`. Also those guards look off, as it's assuming `a` is a function. As for the parsing though, it needs to be Maybe likely because the String may not be parsable as a Card.

Comment: @Jesse that doesn't look very much like Haskell, maybe have a look at https://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions for example...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Firstly,

```
instance Show Card where show (Card a b) 
     = show a ++ show (tail show b)
```

You have automatically derived a `Show` instance for `Card`, so this will conflict (you can only have 1 instance), and further it won't compile. The `show` should go on a new line, and `tail` should be applied to the *result* of `show b`.

```
instance Show Card where 
    show (Card a b) = show a ++ " " + tail (show b)
```

2) Secondly,

```
toCard :: String -> Maybe Card
toCard all@(x:xs)
        | (x=A|B|C|D|E|F)&&(xs==1|2|3) = Just Card
        | otherwise  = Nothing
```

The syntax `(x=A|B|C|D|E|F)&&(xs==1|2|3)` is pretty wild, and certainly not valid Haskell. The closest approximation would be something like, `` x `elem` ['A','B','C','D','E','F'] && xs `elem` ["1","2","3"] ``, but as you can see this rapidly becomes boilerplate-y. Also, `Just Card` makes no sense - you still need to use the `x` and `xs` to say what the card actually is! eg. `Just $ Card x xs` (though that still won't work because they're still character/string not Suit/Rank).

One solution would be to automatically derive a `Read` instance on `Rank`, `Suit`, and `Card`. However, the automatic derivation for `read` on `Card` would require you to input eg. `"Card A R1"`, so let's try using the instance on `Rank` and `Suit` to let us write a parser for `Card`s that doesn't require prefixed `"Card"`.

First attempt:

```
toCard :: String -> Maybe Card
toCard (x:xs) = Just $ Card (read [x] :: Suit) (read xs :: Rank)
```

Hmm, this doesn't really allow us to deal with bad inputs - problem being that `read` just throws errors instead of giving us a `Maybe`. Notice however that we use `[x]` rather than `x` because `read` applies to `[Char]` and `x :: Char`. Next attempt:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

toCard :: String -> Maybe Card
toCard [] = Nothing
toCard (x:xs) = let mSuit = readMaybe [x] :: Suit
                    mRank = readMaybe xs :: Rank
                in case (mSuit, mRank) of
                    (Just s, Just r) -> Just $ Card s r
                    _ -> Nothing
```

This copes better with bad inputs, but has started to get quite long. Here's two possible ways to shorten it again:

```hs
 -- using the Maybe monad
 toCard (x:xs) = do mSuit <- readMaybe [x]
                    mRank <- readMaybe xs
                    return $ Card mSuit mRank

 -- using Applicative
 toCard (x:xs) = Card <$> readMaybe [x] <*> readMaybe xs
```

Comment: The derived `Show` instance for Card wouldn't give the desired instance away.

Comment: Good point, by "extraneous" i primarily meant that you can only have one or the other, not both, but that wasn't clear @chepner

Answer (score 3):

A parser library, though it comes with a steeper learning curve, makes this simpler. For this example, we'll use `Text.Parsec`, from the `parsec` library. Import it, and define a type alias for using in defining your parsers.

```
import Text.Parsec
type Parser = Parsec String ()  -- boilerplate
```

`Parsec String ()` indicates a type of parser that consumes a stream of characters, and can produce a value of type `()` after parsing is complete. (In this case, we only care about the parsing, not any computation done along side the parsing.)

For your core types, we'll define a `Show` instant by hand for `Rank` so that you don't need to strip the `R` off later. We'll also derive a `Read` instance for `Suit` to make it easier to convert a string like `"A"` to a `Suit` value like `A`.

```
data Suit = A|B|C|D|E|F|G deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

data Rank = R1|R2|R3 deriving (Eq)
-- Define Show yourself so you don't constantly have to remove the `R`
instance Show Rank where
    show R1 = "1"
    show R2 = "2"
    show R3 = "3"

data Card = Card Suit Rank deriving Eq
instance Show Card where
    show (Card s r) = show s ++ show r
```

With that out of the way, we can define some parsers for each type.

```
-- Because oneOf will fail if you don't get one
-- of the valid suit characters, read [s] is guaranteed
-- to succeed. Using read eliminates the need for a
-- large case statement like in rank, below.
suit :: Parser Suit
suit = do
    s <- oneOf "ABCDEF"
    return $ read [s]

rank :: Parser Rank
rank = do
    n <- oneOf "123"
    return $ case n of
        '1' -> R1
        '2' -> R2
        '3' -> R3

-- A Card parser just combines the Suit and Rank parsers    
card :: Parser Card
card = Card <$> suit <*> rank

-- parse returns an Either ParseError Card value;
-- you can ignore the exact error if the parser fails
-- to return Nothing instead.
toCard :: String -> Maybe Card
toCard s = case parse card "" s of
                Left _ -> Nothing
                Right c -> Just c
```

---

`oneOf` is a predefined parser that consumes exactly one of the items in the given list.

`parse` takes three arguments:

1. A parser
2. A "source name" (only used for error message; you can use any string you like)
3. The string to parse